# Get method names of un-managed components from Prog Ids using C#

Tags: c#, reflection, com

I want to get the method names of un-managed components. I would be doing using the prog-id

```
System.Type wiType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID("WindowsInstaller.Installer");
object objWI = System.Activator.CreateInstance(wiType);

//Type ty = objBLType.GetType();
foreach (MethodInfo mem in wiType.GetMethods())
{
  Console.WriteLine(mem.Name.ToString());
}
```

Running this doesnt give the method names in `WindowsInstaller.Installer.`

How can this be achieved.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think it can. One of the reasons why .NET was so different from COM is that all of the required metadata is carried around within .NET assemblies, whereas COM needed additional features, such as type libraries. I don't think you can do much in terms of reflection against COM types, since reflection relies on the metadata.

Comment: http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-interop/8249/Introspecting-COM-Object-in-C

Comment: L.B / Damien thanks for the response - but it seems to work on some and not on others - as in the link IDispatch needs to be implemented. is there any other way we can do it to get all the values. If not possible through dot net i guess we can use native c++ to do it? is there a sample link.